# Resize ImageView within SplitPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have an ImageView wrapped in a StackPane that is added to the top section of a SplitPane. When I move the SplitPane's divider, I want the ImageView to resize to fit the allotted space, while also preserving the ImageView's size ratio. I have attempted to achieve this with the following code snippet:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
        image.fitHeightProperty().bind(stackpane.heightProperty());
        image.fitWidthProperty().bind(stackpane.widthProperty());
        image.setPreserveRatio(true);
    });
```

The problem with this however is that the ImageView will only grow, but not shrink. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `root` here? Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: @James_D Sorry, the root is a stackpane, I changed the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved! Playing with the SplitPane's divider bindings seemed to be the solution. It isn't perfect, as sometimes the image is not flush with either top/bottom nor left/right edges depending on the width/height of the Stage, but it gets the job done.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    image.fitWidthProperty().bind(splitPane.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty().multiply(splitPane.widthProperty()));
    image.fitHeightProperty().bind(splitPane.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty().multiply(splitPane.heightProperty()));
    imgWebCamCapturedImage.setPreserveRatio(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a way to resize an ImageView in a SplitPane, you can use a StackPane.

```
    val iv = ImageView()
    val vbox = VBox()
    VBox.setVgrow(vbox, Priority.ALWAYS)
    vbox.widthProperty().addListener { observable, oldValue, newValue ->
        iv.fitWidth = newValue.toDouble()
    }
    vbox.heightProperty().addListener { observable, oldValue, newValue ->
        iv.fitHeight = newValue.toDouble()
    }
    iv.isManaged = false
    val stack = StackPane(vbox, iv)
    val sp = SplitPane(VBox(), stack)
```

This creates a stack pane containing an empty VBox and an ImageView.  When the VBox is resized, the ImageView fit properties are changed to match the new size.  Since the image view "isManaged" is set to false, its size is ignored for deciding the layout allowing the split pane to be dragged to change the size of the VBox in the bottom of the stack.